# Stop WCF request from reaching a method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a requirement where i need to stop the WCF request from reaching a service method in certain conditions. I read many articles where it says to implement a Message Inspector and write the condition in the AfterReceiveRequest method.

My Question is, is it the best place to do this, or is there a better place in the pipeline where i can implement this?

Any samples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can halt request either in custom class deriving *IDispatchMessageInspector* or in custom class deriving *IOperationInvoker*. First one is invoked when message/request is received, latter right before operation is invoked so you can suppress its kick-off.

Comment: I think deriving IDispatchMessageInspector would be ideal. If i through a Fault exception in the derived class of the above, will that break the service or is there some nice way to tell the client that the method cannot be invoked due to the condition?

Comment: You can either throw an exception or return data which comprises reason of service's inability to invoke specific operation.

Answer (score 1):

> i need to stop the WCF request from reaching a service method in
>   certain conditions.

Apparently, to me it looks like on certain condition you don't want to invoke the service method at all; if that's the case then you can probably check for that condition and skip the service call in your consuming client itself. (OR) am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But that condition cannot be checked at the client end because the methods that needs to be stopped from calling will be decided at the service end using a xml configuration file. This file will be altered time to time.